# how to zero copy in a Qt C++ programme?

Tags: qt, zero-copy

I have to implement zero copy method in a program in Qt C++,I read about it and got transferto() method.as described below:
public void transferTo(long position, long count, WritableByteChannel target);

but i can't understand how it works.It is written that Internally, it depends on the underlying operating system's support for zero copy.
So I tried to write a function but i didn't get the meaning of "position" and "channel" here.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What language? `transferTo(..)` is Java IIRC.

Comment: In C++.is there any substitute for transferto() in C++?

Answer (score 4):

There is no cross-platform way to do zero copy in C++, and there is no zero-copy API in Qt. You can implement it for your target OS using provided API:

> Linux supports zero copy through system calls such as sys/socket.h's
>   sendfile, sendfile64, and splice. Windows supports zero copy through
>   the TransmitFile API.

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-copy#Programmatic_access)

Comment: that means i have to write a function to copy data in socket buffer to my intended place.and can u explain me the transferto() function i.e what is channel and position here so that i can implement my own function.

Comment: Please refer to the mentioned APIs' documentation. I'm not familiar with them.

Comment: Unfortunately `TransmitFile` only works between a handle and a network socket. It'd be cool if you could use it for copying files between non-network devices, or moving data between pipes, etc, but that's alas not the case :(